# cordova 3.4.0 working with paypal plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, paypal, cordova-plugins

I am creating phonegap project using cordova 3.4.0 for ios. I want to add paypal payment gateway on my project. I installed the paypal plugin from following link https://github.com/Eaiman/phonegap-paypal-plugin.git

But i am getting following error on xcode.

**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)   "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)   "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**

Please Guide Me.

Answer (score 3):

Dave from PayPal here.

@Arunkumar1775, you are apparently trying to use an old, non-maintained, third-party PhoneGap project.

Instead, please try PayPal's official [Cordova/Phonegap Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-cordova-plugin).

Comment: Hi Dave, I installed this plugin but nothing will happened. Please guide me

Comment: @Arunkumar1775 there is a lot of information on that page about integrating this plugin with your app, including sample code. The page also includes links to additional documentation for the PayPal Mobile SDK.